# Обработка изображений в qt4

Tags: qt, linux

Как в среде разработки qt4 загрузить фотографию любого формата, получить доступ к пикселям, считывать и изменять их?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
QImage img("in.png");
QColor color(0, 255, 0, 255);
img.setPixel(10,10, color.rgb());
```

Обратите внимание что в этом примере QImage создается на стеке.

Answer (score 1):

По хорошему надо так:
uchar *pixels = im.bits();

Теперь pixels - указатель на первый байт рисунка. Пиксели хранятся как двумерный массив. Если изображение в формате RGB, то на каждый пиксель идет 3 байт, первый отвечает за r и т.д.
Пусть w - ширина изображения, h - высота изображения, тогда чтобы залить rbg - картинку зеленым цветом, надо воспользоваться следующим кодом:

```
for( int y = 0; y<h; ++y )
  for( int x = 0; x<w; ++x)
  {
    pixels[ 3*(y*w+x)    ] = 0;
    pixels[ 3*(y*w+x) +1 ] = 255;
    pixels[ 3*(y*w+x) +2 ] = 0;
  }
```

Comment: а чем мой вариант не 'по-хорошему'?

Comment: Медленней. Доступ к памяти напрямую намного быстрее и можно для той же заливки более оптимально копировать память.